# how to set svn Revision number on Last Build Label on CruiseControl.net

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am working on Cruise Control and I wanted to display current build revision number on Last Build Label which is showing in Cruise Control main screen.how to pass revision no dynamically on below code

```
<labeller type="assemblyVersionLabeller">
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
        <revisiom>547</revision>
        <incrementOnFailure>false</incrementOnFailure>
    </labeller>
```

my msbuild scripts is below

```
<SvnCheckout RepositoryPath="$(SvnCheckoutPath)"
        LocalPath="$(CheckOutPath)"
        UserName="username"
        Password="pass123">
      <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
    </SvnCheckout>
```

when I am calling this scripts then I got revision number.
so if my build is succeeded then it should be appeared in **LastBuildLabel** on CCNET screen.please suggest how to achieve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way to get the SVN revision to show up.

```
In order to get this showing you need to edit the .xsl file used to display the summary page.

1. Open {$CC Installation Root}\webdashboard\xsl\header.xsl
2. Go to the bottom of the file and locate the "Last Log Entry" section. It should look like this.

<tr>
    <td class="header-label" valign="top"><nobr>Last log entry:</nobr></td>
    <td class="header-data"><pre><xsl:value-of select="comment"/></pre></td>
</tr>


3. Copy & Paste this section directly underneath it and edit is as shown here

<tr>
    <td class="header-label" valign="top"><nobr>Last log entry:</nobr></td>
    <td class="header-data"><pre><xsl:value-of select="comment"></pre></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="header-label" valign="top"><nobr>SVN Revision:</nobr></td>
    <td class="header-data"><pre><xsl:value-of select="changeNumber"/></pre></td>
</tr>


4. Save the changes to header.xsl
```

From :

http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/01/add-subversion-revision-to.html

Comment: i have followed but nothing to change.pls let me guild

Comment: Did you reset IIS?  (If that doesn't make sense, then reboot the machine)